# Использую в игре бесплатные изображения. Как не быть забаненым на GP?

Tags: google-play, лицензирование

Собираюсь скоро заливать игру на GP. Интересует вопрос по поводу авторских прав / лицензионного соглашения разработчика.

Использую в игре бесплатные для (не)комерческого использования изображения с указанием авторства. (Фрипик) Получил от них письмо, что правильно указал их авторство в самой игре. В какое место :) мне нужно еще отправить информацию в гугол что бы у того не возникло ко мне вопросов? Это же ведь не политика конфиденциальности?

Дело в том, что общался с человеком который получил бан за использование изображений в своём приложении хотя у последнего есть письмо, в котором ему разрешают использовать данные картинки. Бан пункт - Нарушение авторских прав (Использование официальных изображений). Вообщем вопрос куда необходимо размещать информацию о эксклюзивных правах на использование того или иного контента.

Comment: А сама игра бесплатная, без рекламы?